transformation on data points to "super-standardize" the third moment
You can 'standardize' the first moment to a value of 0 by applying:
$$
x - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i} x_{i} \text{ }( = x - \mu)
$$
to each data point;
And you can 'standardize' the second moment to a value of 1 by applying:
$$
\frac{x-\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i} x_{i}}{\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{j}(x_{j}-\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k} x_{k})^{2}}{N}}} \text{ }( = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma})
$$
can this be done for the third moment - setting it to a value of 0.
(and the fourth setting it to a value of 1 and the fifth setting it to 0 etc...)
The effect of this should be to transform data from a skewed normal distribution to a normal in a predictable and invertible way. I need this so I can perform 3rd order moment morphing between probability distributions.
(note this is not normal standardization as this does not fix the skew)

I don't know what you mean by "a skewed normal distribution" (as opposed to just a skewed distribution), or by "3rd order moment morphing." (If that means something that makes sense, I'd write "3rd-order moment morphing" because I think there is much to be said in favor of the more traditional way of using hyphens. Newspapers, magazines, and publishers of fiction have kept that usage alive although it has been abolished in packaging and advertising. But skip this parenthetical comment and resume reading below.)
Skewness of a probability distribution is often defined as
$$
\frac{\text{3rd central momoent}}{(\text{variance})^{3/2}},
$$
where
$$
\text{3rd central moment} = \operatorname E((X-\mu)^3).
$$
Skewness, thus defined, invariant under changes in scale, thus invariant under changes in the units of measurement.
Kurtosis, when defined as the fourth central moment over the square of the variance, is also invariant under such changes.
